# MinGW adds .exe to executables

Tags: g++, mingw

When I use g++ with MinGW:

```
g++ -o myProgram myProgram.cpp
```

g++ gives me not myProgram, but myProgram.exe. I know it doesn't have to name executables .exe, because

```
g++ -o a.out myProgram.cpp
```

produces a.out, with no .exe, and it does run.

I don't like the extension because it's more complicated now to make a Makefile that will work in both Unix and MinGW, especially if I want to `make clean`. Is there a way to tell MinGW's g++, use the name I give you with -o, without changing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to add the .exe extension, just add a dot to the output filename:

```
g++ -o myProgram. myProgram.cpp
```

Comment: That works for g++! It doesn't work for rm, thought; `rm myProgram` tries to remove something with a . at the end. This is going to be a problem in the Makefile, as I can't rm the same thing I produce with g++. ?

Comment: I don't understand. Did you mean `rm myProgram.` ?

Comment: @TopologicalSort: How could you get that wrong?! Dots are what this is all about! Anyway, that's another question.